# Limit and unbounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence of a non-zero number such that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0 \, .$$
>   Prove that $1/a_n$ is not bounded.

I wrote out the definition of limit and definition of bounded sequence. I am trying to prove by contradiction. However I did not get anywhere. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $|\frac{1}{a_n}|$ were bounded by, say, $M$ we could rearrange

$$\left|\frac 1 {a_n} \right| \le M \implies |a_n| \ge \frac{1}{M}$$

for all $n$.

Comment: could u give me more. I am in a rush. Please

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf No. I don't work on someone else's time-table here. The hint is quite adequate if you give it some effort.

Comment: Do you prove by contradiction?

Comment: could u give a little intermediate hint?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf Try thinking about it for a little while longer. Do you know how to negate the definition of convergence, for example?

Comment: -M<=1/a_n<=M >>> 1/M<=a_n does this work but how to make |a_n| > 1/M?

Comment: Please change to M to n. The last letter of your answer.

Comment: @user710587 Thank you.